# How to iterate through custom ArrayList to move to the next item when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

i am new to android and even programming its been only 3 weeks 
i am trying to build an app for my german lesson through showing pics and playing audio.
my problem now, i have a list view which displays a small pic and a word and then i made an onItemClickListener for this list view and it displays items form and arraylist of type **Word**(a class made for the Constructor and get methods for image resources and audio resources and a String for the word it self)

anyway i managed when item clicked on the itemlist it open popup layout that displays image and a play button.

then i wanted to add next and prev buttons to go for next image and audio instead of closing the popup and click on the wanted item again But with no luck at all.

i will try to post most important code related

```
public class Lesson1Words extends AppCompatActivity {


private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;


private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        releaseMediaPlayer();

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ArrayList<Word> lessone1Words = new ArrayList<>();

    lessone1Words.add(new Word("vernünftig", R.drawable.vernunftig, R.raw.l01_vernunftig));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("großzügig", R.drawable.groszugig, R.raw.l01_grosszugig));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("fair", R.drawable.fair, R.raw.l01_fair));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("intelligent/klug", R.drawable.intelligent, R.raw.l01_intelligent));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("frech", R.drawable.frech, R.raw.l01_frech));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("kreativ", R.drawable.kreaiv, R.raw.l01_kreativ));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("sparsam", R.drawable.sparsam, R.raw.l01_sparsam));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("realistisch", R.drawable.realistisch, R.raw.l01_realistisch));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("hübsch", R.drawable.hubsch, R.raw.l01_hubsch));
    lessone1Words.add(new Word("aufmerksam", R.drawable.aufmerksam, R.raw.l01_aufmerksam));

     final WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, lessone1Words, R.color.lesson_color);
     final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.word_list);


    assert listView != null;
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, long l) {

            final Word word = lessone1Words.get(position);

             //open Popup layout for the image but still can't iterate through the arraylist
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                    = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);


            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // when touch outside the Popup layout it dismiss it
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            //change image in ImageView of Popup.xml to current image in the array

            final ImageView imageBig = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popimage);

            imageBig.setImageResource(word.getImageResourceId());

               ImageView playSound = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.play_image);
            playSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //responsible for the playback of the audio according to the arraylist index
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Lesson1Words.this, word.getAudioResourceId());
                    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);

                }
            });
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(listView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


             ImageView nextImage = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.next_image);

            nextImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

            // cant go for the nextimage or audio


                }
            });
        }
    });.
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can close the current popup there and create a new popup using for the next/previous item using the position parameter from the onItemClickListener.

Comment: Please post what you tried, as it sounds a simple call to get(position+1) and setting the new images, should work.

Comment: @lionscribe i tried this  Word word1 = lessone1Words.get(position+1);
imageBig.setImageResource(word1.getImageResourceId());// but it goes for next image only one time it doesn't continue

Comment: Also, you should be calling showAtLocation all the way at the end (though it shouldn't make difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating popup window, set a tag with position value

```
imageBig.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
```

In the onClick function call

```
int pos = imageBig.getTag()+1;
imageBig.setTag(Integer.valueOf(pos));
WordNext = getPosition(position);
...
```

Comment: setTag for the int position unfortunately caused error  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: now i put the setTag right after the popup showing but the position cannot be used inside onClick cause its final variable

Comment: I changed the code to implicitly use Integer.valueOf().

Comment: So set to new variable named pos. I updated the code.

Comment: it worked thanks very much another thing when it reached the last item and user try to click again app crashed

Comment: i = position;
imageBig.setTag(i);

 i= (int) imageBig.getTag();
      i++;
 imageBig.setTag(i);
 Word word1 = lessone1Words.get(i);
 imageBig.setImageResource(word1.getImageResourceId());

Comment: For that you just have to check of pos is higher or equal the number of items in lessone1Words. Also, you may want to show arrow as disabled when there are no more items to be shown, but that is for later.